# RewriteRule regex issue - how to fix `/apis` return index.php?url=apis

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

The current `RewriteRule` failed on `/apis` (must return index.php?url=apis)

```
RewriteRule ^api\/?([^\/]*)$ index.php?api&url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Valid:

- /api return index.php?api&url=`[empty]`
- /api/user return index.php?api&url=user

Failed:

- /apis return index.php?api&url=s, but instead must return index.php?url=apis

**Update:** any character after `/api` if does not starts with slash `/` must return index.php?url=`[any character]` - /apirf8ty76 must return index.php?url=apirf8ty76

/api still must return index.php?api&url=`[empty]` and /api/user return index.php?api&url=user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your conditions to this to make it working:

```
RewriteRule ^api(?:/([^/]*))?$ index.php?api&url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead in your first regex, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^api(?!s)\/?([^\/]*)$ index.php?api&url=$1
```

that should do what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I was not enough clear with my question, I just updated it. Your regex works fine for `/apis`, but will not fix the issue in case when `/api` next character will be some other character except slash `/`.